# How does this code align pointer to 64-bit boundary?

Tags: c, memory, pointers, alignment

I would like to know how this piece of code aligns pointer to 64-bit boundary? I found this code in uboot cpu/mpc85xx/ether_fcc.c. Here the underlying ethernet controller mandates buffer pointer to be aligned to 64-bit boundary.

```
uint cbd_bufaddr;
volatile uchar *NetRxPackets[PKTBUFSRX];
cbd_bufaddr = (uint)NetRxPackets[i];
```

I believe the below check is mandatory to ensure that the pointer is 
64-bit aligned, but I don't see it anywhere in uboot code .

```
if (cbd_bufaddr % 8 != 0)
    cbd_bufaddr += 8 - cbd_bufaddr % 8;
```

I would really appreciate , if someone can point out if I am missing something obvious?

Comment: You haven't indicated where the value in NetRxPackets[i] came from, and that's what needs to be aligned.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing in that original code guarantees anything about alignment.  Your first code block just pulls a pointer out of the `NetRxPackets` array and sticks it into `cbd_bufaddr`.  There's no indication from the code you've provided that the pointers inside that array have any alignment restrictions.  You'll need to show us the code that initializes that array for us to tell you more about what's going on.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I'm not sure that 64-bit values being aligned on 64-bit boundaries is required on 32-bit systems.  Let me pull up the spec and clarify.

Comment: I didn't see anything about that when I looked at the spec, which seems right to me.  In this case, it's an array of pointer types, so that seems likely to have native alignment.

Comment: It's actually the values stored in the array that need to have the correct alignment, anyway - the alignment of the array itself is irrelevant.

Comment: caf is right. Why was this answer uprated? The OP's question is deficient because, for all we know, the values in NetRxPackets are already aligned -- say, by being returned by malloc, which allocates memory on doubleword boundaries on many systems.

Comment: @Jim & @caf are totally right; I was seeing an `&` that isn't there.  Let me go fix this answer up.